# How to pull out object heading from an array

Tags: node.js

I have a JSON response structure like this

```
{
    "_id": "620e97d76ca392a43097cca6",
    "user": "620295cbd67ece90802d2522",
    "orderId": "EnrL7C",
    "Items": [
        {
            "product": {
                "name": "Fresh Salad",
                "id": "61f2911723ff35136c98ad3e"
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 1250,
            "_id": "620e97d76ca392a43097cca7"
        },
    ],
}
```

But i want the product not to be an object, so it should look like this

```
{
    "_id": "620e97d76ca392a43097cca6",
    "user": "620295cbd67ece90802d2522",
    "orderId": "EnrL7C",
    "Items": [
        {
          "name": "Fresh Salad",
           "id": "61f2911723ff35136c98ad3e",
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 1250,
            "_id": "620e97d76ca392a43097cca7"
        },
    ],
}
```

This is my code responsible for the response output

```
  exports.getOrder = (req,res) => {
    Order.findOne({orderId: 'EnrL7C'})
    .populate("Items.product", "name")
    .exec((error, order) => {
     if(error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
     if (order) {
       return res.json(order);
     }else{
       return res.json(['No order found']);
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when I'm too lazy to look up all the mongoose documentation and figure out what version I'm on etc, I use the `.lean()` to just convert it to a normal JS object, which I'm way more comfortable with.

```js
exports.getOrder = (req, res) => {
  Order.findOne({ orderId: "EnrL7C" })
    .lean() // add lean
    .populate("Items.product", "name")
    .exec((error, order) => {
      if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
      if (order) {
        // fix the structure in javascript
        order.Items = order.Items.map((item) => {
          const flat = {
            ...item.product,
            ...item,
          };
          delete flat.product;
          return flat;
        });
        return res.json(order);
      } else {
        return res.json(["No order found"]);
      }
    });
};
```

Let me know if that doesn't work, so I can update the answer.

Comment: It worked. thank you for the help!